# Exact/Approximate Confidence Interval of Parameter Ratio from two Samples of iid Exponential

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, confidence-interval, exponential-distribution, exact-test

Suppose 2 independent samples $X_1,...,X_n \sim Exp(\lambda_1)$ and $Y_1,...,Y_m \sim Exp(\lambda_2)$, and are iid within samples.

I am thinking about how to make an exact confidence interval for $\theta$ where $\theta = \lambda_1/\lambda_2$. Some immediate thoughts, I can try to come up with a pivotal quantity, such as $\lambda_1 \sum X_i \sim Gamma(n,1)$ and $\lambda_2 \sum Y_i \sim Gamma(m,1)$. If I take the ratio of the two, I have $\frac{m \lambda_1 \sum X_i}{n\lambda_2 \sum Y_i} \sim F_{2n,2m}$.

In light of the duality between confidence intervals and hypothesis testing, say we wish to test $H_0: \theta \equiv \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2} = \theta_0$ and $H_a: \theta \equiv \frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2} \neq \theta_0$. Then from above, we can use the fact that $\frac{m \lambda_1 \sum X_i}{n\lambda_2 \sum Y_i} \sim F_{2n,2m}$ to get $\frac{\sum X_i}{\sum Y_i}\sim \frac{n}{m\theta_0} F_{2n, 2m}$. So we would reject $H_0$ at level $\alpha$ by setting the rejection region as $\frac{\sum X_i}{\sum Y_i} \leq \frac{n}{\theta_0 m}F_{2n, 2m}(\alpha/2)$ and $\frac{\sum X_i}{\sum Y_i} \geq \frac{n}{\theta_0 m}F_{2n, 2m}(1-\alpha/2)$.

Thus the confidence interval, in which we are more concerned with the complement of the rejection region over $\theta$, would be $\frac{n\sum Y}{m \sum X}F_{2n, 2m}(\alpha/2) \leq \theta \leq \frac{n\sum Y}{m\sum X}F_{2n, 2m}(1-\alpha/2)$.

To test this theory out, I used R to simulate 23 observations from $Exp(\lambda_1= 3)$ and 45 observations from $Exp(\lambda_2 = 5)$. $\sum X = 4.2689$ and $\sum Y = 6.8285$. We know that the true $\theta = \lambda_1/\lambda_2 = 0.6$. Using the confidence interval built above, we get $\theta \in (0.4819, 1.3298)$ at the $\alpha = 0.05$ level.

Are there other ways to make an exact test that leads to different intervals and rejection regions?

How would one go about making an approximate/large sample test for this?

Note: This is not from a problem set. I am just completing some thought exercises based off statistics courses I taken many years ago.